# How to create multiple animations in Maya?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

I've seen many .FBX models that contain multiple animations along with a model: walk, run, fall, etc..
It's pretty straight-forward to create a single animation in Maya (per scene)... but how do you create multiple animations ??

For instance, a character walks, runs, falls, etc..
How do you store and transfer these different animations from Maya to Unity ?

Comment: Put all the animations in a row on your model, then after importing into Unity you can specify each set of frames to be a different animation.

Comment: You can make a clip.